# High Availability with hot-standby and auto-failover in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

I was asked to implement a High Availability and auto-failover in postgresql and I have been searching the internet all over to find the right architecture for that.

I have tried to do it in two architectures:

1. RedHat cluster
2. UCARP

Both ways came out pretty bad when I've meet bugs on UCARP restarting as master-master after several reboots and Redhat cluster fails to manage properly PostgreSQL service.

I would like to ask if anyone has ever succeeded to implement such an architecture and would like to explain me how or refer me to a tutorial that actually works.

The components that I have are: PostgreSQL at latest version (9.4), RHEL 6.6 and higher, all on virtual machines.

Thanks in advance,
Aviel Buskila.

Comment: "latest version" = 9.4? Remember, these questions last a while - it's worth being specific, since later on it won't be the latest version anymore.

Comment: yes currently it's 9.4, I will update it. thanks for the tip!